# How to achieve by elements addition for list in Groovy?

Tags: list, groovy

Is it possible to achieve by elements addition for list with Groovy closure or build-in functionality? Use of addition operator causes simple lists concatenation.

```
def firstList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def secondList = [5, 6, 7, 8]
def resultList = firstList + secondList // It has to be by elements addition closure here

assert resultList == [6, 8, 10, 12] // Assertion failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[ firstList, secondList ].transpose()*.sum()
```

Comment: Just be careful that length of resulting list will be the minimum of the two, if two lists have varying length.

Comment: Correct. Best case scenario is with both lists having same size. @ghoshak